# which is correct " The dreams often portray..." or " Dreams ofthen portray..."

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

The dreams often portray.. or  Dreams often portray..

which out of two is correct way to start this sentence, thank you

Comment: Are you referring to a specific set of dreams, or to dreams in general?

Comment: Dreams in general

Answer (score 2):

### They're both correct, technically. But they refer to different things.

---

Imagine an oracle who had a set of special dream prophecies. They were written down and studied for centuries. Throughout the prophecies, there are frequent references to a great tree.

Now, if you wanted to talk about *only the oracle's dreams*, then you would say something like,

> The dreams often portray a great tree.

'The dreams' points specifically to a certain set of dreams, not dreams in general.

---

But... What about dreams in general? Since you're not pointing to a specific dream, you can drop the article in front of 'dreams' to make it indefinite. Basically...

> Dreams often portray one's innermost feelings.

This refers to the dreams in general.

Comment: this is the whole sentence:  The dreams often portray an individual's prevalent psychological state of mind.

Comment: Again, it depends on context. Do the preceding or following sentences single out a specific set of dreams? If the sentence before was _Dreams about death are closely related to depression and suicide_, then 'the dreams' in your sentence would be referring to 'dreams about death.' In general, if you want to refer to something in general, drop the article and refer to it in the indefinite.

Comment: Following sentence singles out a specific dream. So I need "The" according to your explanation. Thank you very much!